# Firefox displays position relative different than Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, position, css-position

I have a webite where i position some events in a calendar with position relative. But the problem is that in Chrome the layout it pixel perfect, but in firefox and IE it does not work at all.

The events get positon about 10px wrong downwards. And my tooltip that also uses relative positoning gets stuck at its "orginial" position.

I have a live demo at: http://jonasolaussen.se/dev3/?page_id=6

You can see the black box positions different in Chrome and Firefox. And when you click on a tooltip it turns up at the date in Chrome but in the bottom left corner in Firefox.

I cannot understand why!?

Please! Help Me!

Comment: SO protocol requires that you post relevant code in your question. Please do.

Comment: Please recreate the problem in a jsfiddle and replace your website URL with your saved jsFiddle - we do not know if we can trust your website and SO users could be at risk. (many will not want to risk clicking an unknown link)

Comment: The black box and the tooltip show in virtually the same position for me in Chrome, Firefox, and IE10.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this would be to use css hack so that you can style it dependant on the browser.

Here is a demo:

```
@media screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .firefox {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/3HYmZ/1/

Here are my references:

http://browserhacks.com/

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post and because of your lack of detail I can't be sure, but quite often the reason for this is that different browsers will render their box models differently when widths, padding, margins etc are not explicitly set. setting widths for the elements you wish to position around will usually solve this problem.